# Unable to read Route Parameter in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have successfully implemented route parameter in Angular JS for my other components in same project and for the new component also I am following the same way but It's not working and I am unable to understand the problem in the code.

Below is the code of my routes file

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomerBillComponent } from '../components/customer_bill.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'add-bill', component: CustomerBillComponent },
    { path: 'add-bill/:customer_reference', component: CustomerBillComponent },
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

(I tried using different routes also, but it didn't work)

Below is the code in My *CustomerBillComponent.ts* file

```
ngOnInit() {
    //When I visit /#/add-bill/CR452152
    let route_location = location['hash'].split('/')[1].toLowerCase();
    console.log(route_location); //prints add-bill in Console
    var customer_reference = this.route.snapshot.params['customer_reference'];
    console.log(customer_reference); //prints undefined
}
```

Did I miss something

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Same problem, same results

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: you might need to use `paramMap` instead of `params`. ie: `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('customer_reference')` this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I face almost the same problems. But the reason was different.

In my scenario, the lending page(Component Specified on routing) was different and I was trying to access the route params on the parent Route Component.

Below is the code to demonstrate my scenario:

**home.module.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//other import statements...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'buy/:mainType/:subType', component: BuyComponent, data: {} },
      { path: 'buy/:mainType', component: BuyComponent, data: { } },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'buy', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutCartComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

So, I had to access the RouteParam values in HomeComponent(Parent) and the Lending page was BuyComponent(Child Route of HomeComponent).

So, I was not getting values of route params using below code:

**//Inside HomeComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.routeText = params['category'];
        this.title = this.formatTitle(this.routeText);
    });
}
```

As the lending page is BuyComponent, the above code will not work. Angular allows to access the route params in the above way only on the landing Component.

I tried a lot and finally got a solution to access the Route Params in parent route Component.

Below is the code to access the same:

**//Inside HomeComponent.ts**

```
const routeChildren = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.children;
if (routeChildren.length) {
    //Your code here to assign route params to the Component's Data Member.
}
```

So, accessing `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.children` instead of `this.route.params` did the trick for me.

Hope this will help if someone lands here in search of the problem like me.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ModuleWithProviders. It's a wrapper for module provider.

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

Comment: your routes file please. Ty

Comment: I tried, but still `customer_reference` is `undefined`, thank for help...

Comment: Are you sure you have declare the route in the constructor?

Comment: I think you should using paramMap instead of params. this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('customer_reference');

Comment: In my constructor `private route: ActivatedRoute` and when I changed Param to paramMap it says **property paramMap does not exist on ActiveRouteSnapshot**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141506/discussion-between-akshay-khale-and-digit).

Comment: paramMap is new property for angular v4.xx. Otherwise params should working.

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params) => {
    console.log(params);
  }
)
```

And see what you get. If that doesn't work it's likely that you try to access a parent route's parameter, in which case you have to step up in the router tree in order to gain access to it.

You can do this with the `.parent` property, like such:

```
this.route.parent.params.subscribe(
  (params) => {
    console.log(params);
  }
)
```

As many times as you need.

Comment: o/p: `Object {}`

Comment: @AkshayKhale For both?